# ElasticSearch .NET Sub Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, nest

```
     var response = client.Search<Timeline>(
         x => x.Query(
             q => q.Bool(
                 b => b.Must(queryContainer)))
                   .Size(0)
                .Aggregations(a => a
                .DateRange("last_24_hours",
                f => f.Field(n=>n.server_time)
                .Ranges(z=>z.From(DateMath.Now.Subtract("24h")).To(DateMath.Now))
                   .Aggregations(
                    agg => agg.DateHistogram("widget_clicked_by_hour",
                    p => p.Field(z => z.server_time)
                    .Interval(DateInterval.Hour)
                    .Format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
                    .OrderDescending("_key"))))
                )
              );
```

I'm trying to get items from widget_clicked_by_hour aggregation but in the nest .net library I don't have access to the items list

[image]

although while debugging I found the items list

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the date histogram buckets for each date range bucket would be

```
var dateRange = response.Aggs.DateRange("last_24_hours");

foreach (var rangeBucket in dateRange.Buckets)
{
    var dateHistogram = rangeBucket.DateHistogram("widget_clicked_by_hour");

    foreach (var histogramBucket in dateHistogram.Buckets)
    {
        // do something with bucket
    }
}
```

Since the date histogram aggregation is a sub-aggregation of the date range aggregation, it can be accessed from each bucket in the date histogram aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 2 things that helped me immensely.

1) I would install the sense plugin from chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en

This gives you a very userfriendly way to build your elasticsearch queries and analysis right in the browser.

2) I would look into using the cardinality aggregation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

If you are trying to get a list, this should give you a list of items and the counts of it (which you can use/ignore)

Comment: The Sense plugin, although still useful, is out of date in terms of the properties available and structure of certain queries. I would recommend using Sense/Console as part of the version of Kibana compatible with the Elasticsearch version you're using as it is updated in line with changes